# Mantendo a relação entre os elementos de vetores depois de uma ordenação em Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Tenho dois vetores X e Y, quero plotar um gráfico XY com eles, ou seja, o elemento na posição X[0] corresponde ao elemento Y[0] e o elemento X[1] ao Y[1] e assim sucessivamente. Porém meu vetor X está desordenado, como eu faria para ordenar somente o vetor X mantendo a relação dos elementos dele com os elementos do vetor Y? Por exemplo, se depois de ordenar o vetor X, o elemento X[0] vá parar na posição X[4], o elemento em Y[0] também vá parar em Y[4] e assim com os demais elementos de Y.

Comment: Já tentou usar o `sort()`? Outra coisa tá usando `numpy`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A forma mais simples é associar os elementos X e Y em pares, e em seguida ordenar esses pares - você pode desassociar os pares em novos vetore X1 e Y1 depois.

Se não estiver usando numpy, a forma mais fácil de fazer isso é com o "zip",  em seguida um uso do "zip" para reverter a associação e separar de volta os vetores:

```
In [34]: x = list(range(10))                                                                                                       

In [35]: import random                                                                                                             

In [36]: random.shuffle(a)                                                                                                         

In [37]: y = [i ** 2 for i in x]                                                                                                   

In [38]: print(x, y)                                                                                                               
[9, 3, 4, 7, 5, 8, 2, 6, 0, 1] [81, 9, 16, 49, 25, 64, 4, 36, 0, 1]

In [39]: xy = sorted(zip(x, y))                                                                                                    

In [40]: print(xy)                                                                                                                 
[(0, 0), (1, 1), (2, 4), (3, 9), (4, 16), (5, 25), (6, 36), (7, 49), (8, 64), (9, 81)]

In [41]: x1, y1 = zip(*xy)                                                                                                         

In [42]: print(x1, y1)                                                                                                             
(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9) (0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81)
```

E pronto. A única atenção é que se você tiver "x" repetidos, o "y" de cada um será levado em conta como critério de desempate. Na verdade isso é até uma vantagem, mas se você quiser ignorar o y completamente na ordenação, basta passar para o `sorted` uma função `key` que ignore o segundo elemento em cada item:

```
xy = sorted(zip(x, y), key=lambda point: point[0])
```

## Entendendo o que se passa

O grande segredo aí é a chamada embutida "zip": no uso normal, ele considera cada parâmetro como um iterável, e funciona ele mesmo como um iterável - e, em cada passo, pega um elemento de um de seus parâmetros. Assim, quando se passam os vetores (sejam eles uma lista, uma sequência, ou qualquer outra coisa que funcione num `for`), ele pega o primeiro e o primeiro, e cria uma tupla com esses dois elementos. Depois o segundo com o segundo, e assim por diante. Como mandamos transformar a saída do `zip` em uma lista, o resultado final é uma lista com os pares de coordenadas - todas fora de ordem.

O `sorted` é tranquilo - ele simplesmente ordena nossa lista de pontos - ao comparar tuplas (cada para com uma coordenada (x, y)) ele compara o primeiro elemento, e só no caso de empate vai comparar o segundo - então a ordenação vai funcionar normalmente.

E por fim, para desempacotar, ao colocar o `*` no prefixo da nossa lista de tuplas, estamos dizendo para o Python: "Olha - eu tenho uma lista aqui, e cada elemento dessa lista vai ser um parâmetro na chamada dessa função". Traduzindo, se minha lista de pontos tem:

```
xy = [(0, 0), (1, 1), (2, 4),]
```

A chamada `zip(*xy)` vai ser entendida pelo Pyhton como se fosse:

```
zip((0, 0), (1, 1), (2, 4))
```

E aí o que o zip faz? Pega o primeiro elemento de cada sequência dessas - ou seja, todas as coordenadas X e cria uma tupla com elas. E depois pega o segundo elemento de cada sequência dessas, o Y, e cria uma tupla com elas - e cada tupla dessas, com todos os X e todos os Y é associada a uma das duas variáveis antes do `=` na linha:

```
x1, y1 = zip(*xy)
```

## Usando o NumPy

Em geral, quando se fala de plotagem, é quase certo que se tenha o NumPy instalado - 
O código acima é para Python normal, usando listas - e aí usamos o `zip`. O Numpy tem ferramentas para juntar vetores, e pegar apenas linhas ou colunas depois, de forma que o zip não é necessário. Ele mesmo tem o `sort`, (e o random.shuffle que usamos para embaralhar o X funciona em arrays do NumPy).

A ideia é exatamente a mesma: juntar o X e Y (dessa vez num np.array com duas linhas), fazer o sort das coordenadas, movendo os "y" junto com o "x", e separar depois (que é opcional, pois num array do numpy já é possível usar os X e Y de um array 2D diretamente):

```
In [41]: import numpy as np                                                                                                        

In [42]: x = np.array(range(10))                                                                                                   

In [43]: random.shuffle(x)                                                                                                         

In [44]: x                                                                                                                         
Out[44]: array([2, 8, 0, 9, 7, 4, 5, 6, 1, 3])

In [45]: y = x ** 2                                                                                                                

In [46]: y                                                                                                                         
Out[46]: array([ 4, 64,  0, 81, 49, 16, 25, 36,  1,  9])

In [47]: xy = np.vstack((x, y))                                                                                                    

In [48]: xy                                                                                                                        
Out[48]: 
array([[ 2,  8,  0,  9,  7,  4,  5,  6,  1,  3],
       [ 4, 64,  0, 81, 49, 16, 25, 36,  1,  9]])

In [49]: xy.sort(axis=0)                                                                                                           

In [50]: xy                                                                                                                        
Out[50]: 
array([[ 2,  8,  0,  9,  7,  4,  5,  6,  1,  3],
       [ 4, 64,  0, 81, 49, 16, 25, 36,  1,  9]])

In [51]: xy.sort(axis=1)                                                                                                           

In [52]: xy                                                                                                                        
Out[52]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [ 0,  1,  4,  9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81]])

In [53]: x1 = xy[0, :]                                                                                                             

In [54]: y1 = xy[1, :]                                                                                                             

In [55]: print(x1, y1)                                                                                                             
[0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9] [ 0  1  4  9 16 25 36 49 64 81]
```

Perceba que a separação final em x1 e y1 é completamente opcional, uma vez que você pode passar `xy[0, :]` - "na linha '0', todos os números do começo até o final" e `xy[1, :]` diretamente para  função de plotagem.